# Magento2 REST auth help needed

Tags: magento2, rest-api, oauth, magento-2.1, integration

I'm hanging on this issues for nearly a week and cannot find any sollution. I'm trying to send a REST request to my new Magento2 store. It worked allready, but then the oauth/token forced authentication was activated, now I can't beak through to the backend.
I tried it with the scribe framework v1.8.0, here's my attempt:

```
public class MagentoApi extends DefaultApi10a {
private static final String BASE_URL = "http://myshopurl.de/";
private static final String AUTHORIZE_URL = "http://myshopurl.de/oauth/oauth_authorize?oauth_token=";
private static final String REQUEST_TOKEN_ENDPOINT = "http://myshopurl.de/oauth/token/request";
private static final String ACCESS_TOKEN_ENDPOINT = "http://myshopurl.de/oauth/token/access";

@Override
public String getAccessTokenEndpoint() {
    return ACCESS_TOKEN_ENDPOINT;
}

@Override
public String getRequestTokenEndpoint() {
    return REQUEST_TOKEN_ENDPOINT;
}

@Override
public String getAuthorizationUrl(OAuth1RequestToken requestToken) {
    return String.format(AUTHORIZE_URL, requestToken.getToken());
}
public static MagentoApi instance() {
    return MagentoApi.InstanceHolder.INSTANCE;
}

private static class InstanceHolder {
    private static final MagentoApi INSTANCE = new MagentoApi();

    private InstanceHolder() {
    }
}
    }
```

And here my testclient:

```
public class AuthTest {

    private static final String CONSUMER_KEY  = "MYCONSUMERKEYHERE";
    private static final String CONSUMER_SECRET  = "MYSECRETKEYHERE";


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        OAuth10aService service = new ServiceBuilder()
                .apiKey(CONSUMER_KEY)
                .apiSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET)
                .debug()
                .build(MagentoApi.instance());
    final OAuth1RequestToken requestToken = service.getRequestToken();
    System.out.println(service.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken));
    final String oauthVerifier = in.nextLine();
    final OAuth1AccessToken accessToken = service.getAccessToken(requestToken, oauthVerifier);
    final OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, The_Magento_Get_Categories_REST_URL, service);
    service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
    final Response response = request.send();
    System.out.println(response.getBody());
 }
}
```

The result is appearing in this line:
            final OAuth1RequestToken requestToken = service.getRequestToken();

this is the sysout:

```
Fetching the Request Token...
obtaining request token from http://myshopurl.de/oauth/token/request
setting oauth_callback to oob
generating signature...
using base64 encoder: CommonsCodec
base string is: POST&http%3A%2F%2Fmyshopurl.de%2Foauth%2Ftoken%2Frequest&oauth_callback%3Doob%26oauth_consumer_key%thekey%26oauth_nonce%3D3285773414%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1467397682%26oauth_version%3D1.0
signature is: u4h6pVZw6tU8aj0NdFljBSB3h9o=
appended additional OAuth parameters: { oauth_nonce -> 3285773414 , oauth_signature -> u4h6pVZw6tU8aj0NdFljBSB3h9o= , oauth_callback -> oob , oauth_consumer_key -> thekey, oauth_timestamp -> 1467397682 , oauth_signature_method -> HMAC-SHA1 , oauth_version -> 1.0 }
using Http Header signature
sending request...
response status code: 401
response body: oauth_problem=Consumer+key+has+expired
```

I'm really begging for help.

Otherwise, is there a possibility to deactivate the authentication via REST at all?

Thank you in advance!

PS: The integration is activated in the backend. I also tried reauthorizing several times.
[image: Integration Authorized]

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message your consumer key has expired.

You need to access your backend under **System > Extensions > Integration** choose your integration and click Activate

The full documentation is available here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-oauth.html

Comment: Hello, maybe I needed to say that the integration is activated, I attached a screenshot

Comment: @Java_Waldi yes but the expiration is 300 seconds you may need to re activate the integration

Comment: As I allready mentioned above, I allready tried reauthorizing several times. I Also tried setting the expiration time to 0 or max value. Result was always the same. The documentation is not helpful at all because there is no java exaample given.